# Add column to dataframe with default value in Deedle

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, f#, deedle

How can I achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517072/add-column-to-dataframe-with-default-value) in [Deedle](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle).

Pandas: `df['Name'] = 'abc'`

Deedle: `df?Name = "abc"` doesn't work - it expects a series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a sample data frame with one column:

```
let df = 
  frame [ "One" => series [ 1 => 1.1; 2 => 2.2 ] ]
```

To add a new column, you will need to create a series with values for all rows first. Then you can add it to the frame in very similar way to pandas:

```
df?Two <- series [ for k in df.RowKeys -> k => "abc" ]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have something like `Frame.addColWith` where one could pass a column name and a function `key -> value` used to produce new value by key? Then I could to this: `Frame.addColWith "Name" (fun k -> "abc")`

Comment: @Anil Absolutely. You can define this function and have it in some common Deedle extensions module in your project, or write a few tests & docs for it and send a PR to Deedle :-)