# How to add a constant value to a column in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to pass constant values in a python pandas data frame, and it is adding the only first row and the rest of the show as NaN. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I tried all the possible answers but it still not working for. If you guys have any idea please let me know

```
weekdayDistance.loc[:,'UID'] = user.UID.head(1)
weekdayDistance['UID'] = user.UID.head(1)
weekdayDistance.loc['UID'] = user.UID.loc[0]

output:
a b c UID
1 1 1  1
2 2 2  NaN
3 3 3  NaN

what I want 
a b c UID
1 1 1  1
2 2 2  1
3 3 3  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below:

```
user['UID'] = 1
```

If just one row is getting filled, you can use `ffill()`. It will replicate the first row's value in all the rows.

```
user.UID = user.UID.ffill()
```

Comment: Did you try the exact statement that I gave? It should work fine.

Comment: I am getting the value from other dataframe and passing the value to this dataframe and the above will work fine but I need the pass from other dataframe

Comment: @vinaykaragod I have updated my answer. Run the `ffill()` statement after you get one row filled with constant value. This will work. Let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer would be

```
df['col_name'] = 1
```

or you can use insert, where 0 is the index of column, followed by column name and its constant value.

```
df.insert(0, colname, value)
```

This [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517072/add-column-to-dataframe-with-constant-value) might give you explanation