# Python: Add part of filename as new column for multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple csv files. For each file, a new column `filename` will be generated where it contains only numeric value. For eg. if filename is `20934_info.csv`, `filename` column only extracts `20934`. It will loop through all CSV files. How can it be done using python?
Sample dataset:

```
    x   y
0   a   NaN
1   b   d
```

Expected output:

```
    x   y   filename
0   a   NaN 20934
1   b   d   20934
```

Code I tried:

```
extension = 'csv'
files = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fp).assign(New=os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0]) 
       for fp in files])
print (df)
```

Comment: Are you getting data from the files? Or just the file names? If it was just names, you could use `df[filename] = int("".join(r'\d+', re.findall(, filepath)))` for each file path. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517072/add-column-to-dataframe-with-constant-value and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: just filenames. Btw the code you provide gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax. @LarrytheLlama

Comment: No problem - I wrote the code without checking it -  it should be something like: `df[filename] = int("".join(re.findall(r"\d+", filepath)))`

Comment: Thanks! Now it works for a single csv file. How can I run a loop for multiple csv files?

Comment: `for filename in filenames: ...` if you have all the filenames ready