# is there a script that can add a column to csv if it does not exist

Tags: python, pandas

im looking for a way to add in a column called q17 and/or q20 if they do not already exist in a csv.

I have around 40 csvs, and i want a scrip that will search each one seeing if it has the columns q17 & q20. If it does not, the script will add in the missing column(s) and leave all the row values blank

```
import pandas as pd
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir('.') if isfile(join('.', f))]
print(onlyfiles)

#add q17 and q20 if missing from csv sheet
df = onlyfiles
if ['q17'] not in df:
        df['q17'] = ''
```

the script below returns the error "‘list’ objecet has no atribute columns" and im not sure why

Comment: You need to call `pd.read_csv()` to read the CSV into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the files, reading each file into a dataframe. Then check if each column exists (see [How to check if a column exists in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870306/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-pandas)) and add it (see [Add column to dataframe with constant value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517072/add-column-to-dataframe-with-constant-value)). If either column needed to be added, rewrite the file.

```
for file in onlyfiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    updated = False
    if 'q17' not in df:
        df['q17'] = ''
        updated = True
    if 'q20' not in df:
        df['q20'] = ''
        updated = True
    if updated:
        df.to_csv(file)
```

Comment: thanks for helping!! i tried using the script above and got the error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 10-11: invalid continuation byte" I think it's referring to df = pd.read_csv(file), but im not sure whats wronng with that since i've used that line before without issue. im using python pandas if that changes anything

Comment: See the `encoding` and `encoding_errors` arguments to `pandas.read_csv`.