# How to apply itertools to a series

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a dataset of patient surgery. Many of the patients have had multiple operations and the value_counts aggregation of their multiple operation codes (there are 4 codes) is shown below.

```
['O011']                                    2785
['O012']                                    1813
['O011', 'O011']                             811
['O013']                                     532
['O012', 'O012']                             522
['O014']                                     131
['O013', 'O013']                             125
['O014', 'O014']                              26
['O012', 'O011']                              24
['O011', 'O012']                              20
['O011', 'O011', 'O011']                      14
['O011', 'O013']                              12
['O012', 'O012', 'O011']                       6
['O011', 'O012', 'O012']                       6
['O011', 'O011', 'O011', 'O011']               5
['O013', 'O013', 'O013']                       5
['O013', 'O011']                               4
['O012', 'O012', 'O012']                       4
['O012', 'O013']                               3
['O013', 'O014']                               3
['O011', 'O013', 'O013']                       3
['O012', 'O014']                               3
['O011', 'O012', 'O011']                       2
['O012', 'O013', 'O013']                       2
['O011', 'O014']                               2
['O013', 'O012', 'O012']                       2
['O014', 'O014', 'O014']                       2
['O013', 'O012']                               1
['O012', 'O012', 'O013', 'O013', 'O013']       1
['O012', 'O011', 'O012']                       1
['O011', 'O011', 'O012']                       1
['O013', 'O013', 'O011']                       1
['O011', 'O011', 'O012', 'O012']               1
['O014', 'O013', 'O013']                       1
['O013', 'O013', 'O012']                       1
['O012', 'O011', 'O011']                       1
['O011', 'O012', 'O013']                       1
['O013', 'O011', 'O011']                       1
['O012', 'O012', 'O012', 'O012']               1
['O013', 'O013', 'O012', 'O012']               1
['O014', 'O013', 'O011', 'O011']               1
['O012', 'O011', 'O011', 'O011']               1
['O013', 'O011', 'O012']                       1
```

This shows the sequence of their operations by patient count, - so 2785 patients have had just the one procedure, - O012.
I want to create a new column with a boolean 'Are all the operations the same'.
There is an itertools recipe for comparing the values in a list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844832/11795964)
I am a surgeon and my python skills are not up to applying it to the series, - how do I create a new column using this function?.

The series is `OPERTN_01_list`
I tried

```
from itertools import groupby

def all_equal(iterable):
    g = groupby(iterable)
    return next(g, True) and not next(g, False)
```

My dataset is `mo` (multiple operations), so I tried to apply the function `all_equal` to the series

```
mo['eq'] = all_equal(mo['OPERTN_01_list'])
```

but the new column `mo['eq']` had all false values.

I am not sure the best way to implement the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute your function here

```py
all_equal(mo['OPERTN_01_list'])
```

This returns a single value because the method sees `mo['OPERTN_01_list']` as the `iterable`, rather than each row. Therefore it's checking something like this:

> does row0 == row1? -> False
>
> does row1 == row2? --> False
>
> ...
>
> does rowN-1 == rowN? --> False

Seeing as the overall value is `False`, setting it to the `mo['eq']` series repeats it for all rows. See this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29517089/6509519)

There are at least three different approaches to getting what I think you want.

## Use [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

Apply the function over the contents of each row in the `mo["OPERTN_01_list"]` series.

```py
mo["OPERTN_01_list"].apply(all_equal)
```

Out

```py
# showing a sample of 5 rows for brevity
26     True
16    False
9     False
11    False
1      True
```

## Use [`.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html)

Pretty much the same as `.apply` but especially useful in [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) operations

```py
mo["OPERTN_01_list"].transform(all_equal)
```

Out

```py
# showing a sample of 5 rows for brevity
1      True
11    False
2      True
8     False
42    False
```

## Vectorize the function with [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) and treat `mo["OPERTN_01_list"]` as the input

This will allow you to keep your code the same but with one minor change

```py
# vectorize the function
all_equal = np.vectorize(all_equal)

all_equal(mo["OPERTN_01_list"])
```

Out

```py
# note that this returns a `np.array` instead of a `pandas.Series`
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False False  True False
 False False  True  True False  True False False False False False False
 False False  True False False False False False False False False False
 False False  True False False False False]
```

Using any of these should get you the result you desire, but I may suggest using one of the first two in case your index changes